# Why rs.next() don't go to another record

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

If I remove `beforeFirst()` my function does only first record in `ResultSet` and go to end. If I use `beforeFirst()` I get an error `ResultSet IS_TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select _id, godziny_id from tblZmiany where harmonogram_id = " + h_id + " order by pracownik_id, Dzien");
    rs.beforeFirst();
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (stat.executeUpdate("insert into tblWykonanie (Zmiana_id, Godziny_id) values ('" + rs.getLong(1) + "', " + rs.getInt(2) + ");") < 1) {
            // Jeśli insert nie wstawił kolejnego rekordu
            error_code = "Wystąpił problem podczas zatwierdzania harmonogramu.";
            return false;
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    error_code = e.getMessage();
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: May be you are resetting rs in .executeUpdate ?

Comment: please which type of SQL engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same `Statement` object for both the `SELECT` and the `INSERT`. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

To fix the problem, use a separate `Statement` object for the `executeUpdate()` call.

Also, I strongly advise you to change the code to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with bound arguments (represented by `?`). Building SQL statements bit by bit as you're doing right now could open up [security vulnerabilities](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a major security flaw. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, use string concatenation with SQL statements; use PreparedStatements instead!

```
 harmonogram_id = " + h_id + " order by pracownik_id,
```

Take a look here to see how your application could be easily owned with simple tricks:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

To answer your question though, it depends on your database. You have to set a property during the connection creation:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                           ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE),
                           ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
```

From:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html#1012735

Comment: Not a best practice, but if `h_id` is an int there's no risk.

Comment: Agree, but I disagree. It may be safe now, but what if your newbie coworker comes along and changes the int to a String so he doesn't have to do as much work on the frontend? The unit tests will still "pass." Better be safe than sorry!